# Does constructor generated by Emscripten bindings guarantee zero-initialization?

Tags: c++, emscripten, embind

When binding a C++ structure to Emscripten like so:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    int n;
};
```

```cpp
#include <emscripten/bind.h>
using namespace emscripten;

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(myproject) {
    class_<Foo>("Foo")
        .constructor<>()
        .property("n", &Foo::n);
}
```

Does the `constructor<>()` declaration guarantee that the `n` member will be initialized to zero when constructed with `new` in JavaScript? I would assume it calls C++'s `Foo()` or `new Foo()`, meaning yes, but I can't find any source confirming this.

Comment: Neither `Foo()` nor `new Foo()` perform zero-initialization, they would both perform default-initialization, leaving `n` indeterminate

Comment: `T()` is called value initialization.  For class types that means default initialization (call the default constructor).  For built in types you get zero initialization.

Comment: @NathanOliver Doesn't value initialization include zero initialization for classes with implicitly-defined default constructor (http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-9.1.2)?

Comment: @DanielLangr Good catch, I forgot about that clause.